# Paste elements together pairwise

Tags: r, lapply

Let's say I have two vectors and a distance matrix like below

```
v1 = sample(c(0,1),5,replace=TRUE)
v2 = sample(c(0,1),5,replace=TRUE)
d = matrix(rep(1,5*5),ncol=5)
diag(d) <- 0
```

Using the function below I'm calculating distance

how do I paste them together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first attempt by removing the inner loop and using the vectorization for the vector2 multiplication and sum:

```
  f_d_categorical2 <- function(vector1, vector2, dist.matrix) {
  ptm <- proc.time()
  dist <- 0
  for (i in 1:length(vector1)) {
      dist <- dist + sum(vector1[i]*vector2*dist.matrix[i,])
  }
  print(proc.time()-ptm)
  return(dist)
}
```

Process time went from 1.8 to 0.03 sec. I am sure there is room for improvement and additional test cases.